# Jquery Replace RegEx All String Values

Tags: jquery

I'm working with Jquery, and I wrote this code for replace all string variable. But not working.

```
var s = ":) :) :)".replace(new RegExp(':)','g'),'<img src="../images/smiley.gif" />');
alert(s);
```

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape the parenthesis :

```
new RegExp(':\\)','g')
```

As you can see, there are two `\` : one because the `)` must be escaped in a regex, and one because a `\` must be escaped in a string literal.

It's simpler to use a regular expression literal :

```
var s = ":) :) :)".replace(/:\)/g,'<img src="../images/smiley.gif" />');
```